# Using editor.action.insertSnippet from another extension

Tags: json, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am trying to add buttons to the status bar of VS Code that insert code-snippets, using this [Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-commands). I also have the following keybindings (in keybindings.json) for these snippets which just work fine.

```
{
    "key": "alt+x l",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == 'markdown'",
    "args": {
        "snippet": "[Text](URL)$0"
    }
}
```

Unfortunatly, I cannot get the arguments-syntax straight to do the same with the extension. I tried quiet a few variations in settings.json but with no success. The button is displayed and the insertSnippet command is executed, unfortunatly not with the passed arguments.

```
        {
            "alignment": "left",
            "priority": -9996,
            "text": "$(file-media)",
            "tooltip": "Insert image reference",
            "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
            "arguments":["{\"snippet\": \"[Text](URL)$0\"}"],
            "filterLanguageRegex": "markdown"
        }
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference if someone runs into the same problem:

The `commands` extension expects an array of commands, the 'insertSnippet` command expects an object with the "snippet" key. The correct syntax is:

```
{
  "alignment": "left",
  "priority": -9996,
  "text": "$(file-media)",
  "tooltip": "Insert image reference",
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "arguments":[{
    "snippet": "[Text](URL)$0"
  }],
  "filterLanguageRegex": "markdown"
}
```